# Nesting Backbone.js Fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

```
this.Model.fetch({
    success: function() {
        ...
        <some code>
        ...

        this.Model.save({
            success: function() {
               alert("Success");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I am trying to Save model and it is working well. But after saving the model the alert is not triggered.

Comment: Even if it's working, could you try to add a callback on error and check if there is one?

Comment: Yes, I added error callback, But it not giving any error.

Comment: Is this behavior because of nesting of model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
this.Model.fetch({
    success: function() {
        ...
        <some code>
        ...

        this.Model.save(null, {
            success: function() {
               alert("Success");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save

```
model.save([attributes], [options])
```

save function has first argument as attributes